video overlaps using exoplayer
i have some issues with exoplayer inside a pager view, the first frame of the previous or next video overlaps with current video shown. It only happens on bigger screens like 6.6inch higher but not on smaller screen. below is the link of the issue. thanks
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_xiCfZL8-9YepDdUs_UKC_C7vgQXiEj2/view
I tried modifying the height and width of the player view but it did not solved the issue

If you are using jetpack compose, use clip with the composable where player view is created, as it would not allow it to overflow, specially when aspect ratio of container is different from the video.
Eg:
Image Ref

You could try clipToOutline to solve the problem:
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        PlayerView(context).apply {
            player = mExoPlayer
            clipToOutline = true   //line to avoid overlaps
        }
    })

If this still doesn't work, you can try this:
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        PlayerView(context).apply {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_exo_player, null, false)
            (view as PlayerView).apply {
                player = mExoPlayer
                clipToOutline = true   //line to avoid overlaps
            }
        }
    })

with my_exo_player being:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:surface_type="texture_view" />    //line to avoid overlaps

